# CodeIgniter Naming Convention for Interfaces

Tags: php, codeigniter, coding-style

I can't seem to find a reference for CodeIgniter's naming convention for interfaces. Is there one? Can anyone suggest one?

FYI: CodeIgniter uses this for classes: `Foo_bar`. Zend uses something like this for interfaces: `Foo_Bar_PluginInterface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by interface, but if you mean Class names, then after a quick look at their documentation tells me you are right with `Foo_bar`.

**Update**

I do not think there is a set convention for the use of interfaces in Codeigniter, at least not stated by Ellislab.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php. I might just copy the convention used in the same. So, I would have iFoo_bar.

Comment: gotcha, sorry, coming from a C# world of abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a naming convention for Codeigniter nor for any other EllisLab product. ExpressionEngine their flagship commercial content management system doesn't have a single interface insight.

Considering Codeigniter hasn't long dropped support for PHP4, it might explain why interfaces aren't used. May I ask why you want to use interfaces in Codeigniter anyway? I can't see any reason too, but yet again, my use of interfaces and abstract classes in PHP is infrequent.